# Answer simple questions with more details

Tags: discussion

What do people think of the following initiative?

> When someone asks a question with a simple, obvious (to us) answer, don't just code-snippet, but take the time to *explain* what's gone wrong, or why the way the OP did it didn't work...

What prompted this suggestion was [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23385/215), but I'm sure there are [plenty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23157/215) of other [examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18157/215)<sup>1</sup> where the answer is just "Do it this way, use this package...". When these arise, perhaps we should try to say "Do it this way, here's why your way doesn't work" or "Use this package, here's why it's hard to do without the package..."

I think we would be building a better collection of questions and answers if the answers not only solved the problem, but helped the readers learn a little more about TeX and friends...

---

<sup>1</sup>OK, these are all questions I have answered, but those are the ones I thought of...

Comment: I can't agree more.

Comment: I also wrote an answer explaining why you need two passes for references to work, but I can't find it...